# Filtering Formatted Date Using Custom Date Filter in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am currently using header filters to filter the data in my Tabulator table.
All columns except date is working.

The date format fed into the table is from a MySQL database and is formatted as such Y-m-d but I would like to reformat it to d/m/Y and still be able to filter on it using the header filter in Tabulator.

I can't find any example of how to do to this, but from reading online it would seem like I need to create a custom date filter, at the moment if I try filtering on d/m/Y, it doesn't work, because in the background it is still formatted as Y-m-d.

Please can somebody provide a working example of a custom date filter and how Tabulator should be configured to use it, I've spent ages on this going through numerous websites, it would be really appreciated, thank you.

**Example of what I want to achieve.
See the Header Filtering in the 'Date Of Birth' column on https://tabulator.info/examples/5.5#filter-header**

Comment: I have removed the PHP tag

Comment: If you are open to using an external library such as `luxon`, you can mutate the date value into the format you need and then the filter should work as expected.  Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tabulator-forked-yl9y4d?file=/src/index.js